# How to see recent file changes on ext3 file system?

Tags: ext3, journaling

Looks like I don't understand the journaling facilities of ext3fs.

I use a Linux server system with a lot of other users having sudo rights. The problem is that often config files are getting changed and system corrupts. And nobody is going to say it is him who was changing the config files.

I guess journaling file system does save the information on user pid who have changed the file and the change time? If it is true, how can I see the log?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect. The journal merely records the changes to the inodes and superblocks, not who performs them. Look into the auditing subsystem instead.

Comment: does Linux kernel have any auditing subsystem inside or do you mean any third-party software?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+auditing+subsystem